# How to set the minimal value of a layer to be displayed in google earth engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

so i'm using OpenLandmap Sand Content and trying to show layer of an area only with average soil sand content above 50%;
here's my attempt

```
    var areas = ee.FeatureCollection('users/sdwijati/IDN_adm2')
    var nama_prov = ['Jawa Barat', 'Jakarta Raya', 'Jawa Tengah',
                      'Jawa Timur', 'Yogyakarta', 'Banten']// 'Sulawesi Tengah']
    var area = areas.filter(ee.Filter.inList('NAME_1', nama_prov));
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    var sand = ee.Image("OpenLandMap/SOL/SOL_SAND-WFRACTION_USDA-3A1A1A_M/v02");
    var sandavg = sand.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());
    var ltsandavg = sandavg.mask(sandavg.lte(50));
    var sandvis= {min: 0, max: 100, palette: ['fbff00','b4ff00','00c4ff','0005ad']};
    Map.addLayer(ltsandavg.clip(area), sandvis)
    Map.centerObject(area, 7)
```

but instead it only shows the area with sand content below 50%, any idea on how to do the opposite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ltsandavg = sandavg.mask(sandavg.lte(50));
```

Let's break this line down a bit.

`sandavg.mask(...)` sets the `sandavg` mask. A mask is an image where `1` means the pixel should be included, and `0` means the pixel should be excluded. (There are some more details to this, but for your question here, it doesn't really matter). Note that it's usually better to call `updateMask()` instead. That will make sure previously masked pixels stay masked.

`sandavg.lte(50)` creates an image where pixels are `1` were `sandavg` is **l**ess **t**han or **e**qual (lte) to `50`, otherwise `0`. This is the image you use to mask `ltsandavg`.

If you want to mask out pixels with `ltsandavg` **g**reater **t**han (gt) 50, it would look like this:

```
var gtsandavg = sandavg.updateMask(sandavg.gt(50));
```

All together:

```
var areas = ee.FeatureCollection('users/sdwijati/IDN_adm2')
var nama_prov = ['Jawa Barat', 'Jakarta Raya', 'Jawa Tengah',
  'Jawa Timur', 'Yogyakarta', 'Banten'
] // 'Sulawesi Tengah']
var area = areas.filter(ee.Filter.inList('NAME_1', nama_prov));
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
var sand = ee.Image("OpenLandMap/SOL/SOL_SAND-WFRACTION_USDA-3A1A1A_M/v02");
var sandavg = sand.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());
var ltsandavg = sandavg.updateMask(sandavg.lte(50));
var gtsandavg = sandavg.updateMask(sandavg.gt(50));
var sandvis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  palette: ['fbff00', 'b4ff00', '00c4ff', '0005ad']
};
Map.addLayer(ltsandavg.clip(area), sandvis)
Map.addLayer(gtsandavg.clip(area), sandvis)
Map.centerObject(area, 7)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0f4d1062a14b0ca9137af176e21d4efe

Comment: aaahh, so that's what .lt and .lte means. thank you so much for your answer